# "babel-node: not found" with react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, dependencies

i getting this type of error while running the other project in my Linux system.

```
sh:  1: babel-node: not found 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERE! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh 
npm ERR! ENOENT errno 
npm ERR! react-native-activity-feed-showcase@.1.0 init-data: babel-node scripts/initData.js
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the init-data script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: please use a title that describes the specific problem.

Comment: The first error is very clear. You haven't installed `babel-node`, or didn't install it properly.

Comment: First i was trying to create a test project using react-native but i found or create some amazing errors that i can't solve for now then i decided to check the framework is really working or installed correctly or not in my system then i go to this github project link " https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-example " and trying to run but still getting errors i have tried this for 2 days but not solving. Please help! .